# MacBook Pro speakers dust

Tags: speakers, macos

The holes of the speakers in the MacBook Pro (the recent model) are closed by dust.
Is there a good way to clean them?

Comment: Have you tried a vacuum or [compressed air](http://amzn.to/2r2w5Zr)?

Comment: I thought of that, won't it make the dust particles to stick harder and deeper in the tiny speaker's holes?

Comment: Not in my experience - especially if you use a vacuum.  There are even a [Micro Attachment Kit](http://amzn.to/2r2Juk9) that can be used on Shop Vacs.  Works every time.

Answer (score 2):

if you have a small vacuum cleaner, like the portable ones for cars or furniture I would suggest you try that. Or even a regular vac if your careful.